# How to change variable value inside the variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
Error_msg=''
input=''
no_null="Error: ${input} can't enter null value"

input='num'
Error_msg=$no_null
echo "$Error_msg"
```

result
`Error:  can't enter null value`

num can't show. How to change the input value?
Thanks in advise.

Comment: Variables are expanded when you assign the variable. It won't autotomatically update `no_null` when you reassign `input`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template that you substitute when you need it.

```
input=''
no_null="Error: <INPUT> can't enter null value"
input='num'
Error_msg="${no_null/<INPUT>/$input}"
echo "$Error_msg"
```

Note that variable substitution with `${variable/old/new}` is a `bash` extension, it may not exist in other shells.

Comment: May want to note substring replacement is a bashism... (in light of the [shell] tag)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `printf` to generate new content in var:

```
no_null="Error: %s can't enter null value"
printf -v Error_msg "$no_null" "$input"
echo "$Error_msg"
```

Answer (score 0):

> change-variable-value-inside-the-variable

Ways of not using 'eval'

bash (with help of prompt expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash

Error_msg='Error: ${input} can'"'t enter null value"

input='num'
echo "${Error_msg@P}"
```

zsh (std nested expansion):

```
#!/bin/zsh

Error_msg='Error: ${input} can'"'t enter null value"

input='num'
echo "${(e)Error_msg}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a function:

```
$ Error_msg() { echo "Error: ${input} can't enter null value"; }
$ input=''
$ Error_msg
Error:  can't enter null value
$ input='num'
$ Error_msg
Error: num can't enter null value
```